# Is there a pattern for defining a "template" resource in a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, web-applications

Let's say I am building a web app (using React, in case that matters) where someone can create a new Widget. Some Widget properties have default values defined in data models in the API. These default values need to be displayed in the UI form for creating the new Widget.

I'd like to avoid duplicating these defaults in the app versus the API data models. Here is a sample data model as defined in the API:

```
Widget
  _id
  name
  messageTextColor (default #999999)
  bodyBackgroundColor (default #FFFFFF)
  someBooleanValue (default true)
  someOtherBooleanValue (default false)
  ... and so on
```

There are over a dozen settings, and many have default values.

I could duplicate these defaults in my UI app:

```
class EditWidgetPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      messageTextColor: '#999999',
      bodyBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      someBooleanValue: true,
      someOtherBooleanValue: false,
      ... etc
    };
  }
}
```

I could also define a resource in my API, `GET /widgets/new`, which returns a "template" widget:

```
{
  name: '',
  messageTextColor: '#999999',
  bodyBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  someBooleanValue: true,
  someOtherBooleanValue: false,
  ... etc
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone can point me to information online (e.g., blog articles) related to a common pattern whereby a "template" resource is accessible in a RESTful API -- or even an alternative approach not listed here.

Answer (score 0):

I worry this is going to be considered 'opinion based', or at least a somewhat unclear answer. Anyway, you might find answers in HATEOAS. Many formats have a 'form' or 'action' concept, and the idea of 'discovering a create form' is a pretty common pattern.

Anyway, I also don't see how you couldn't just:

1. Fetch a 'template' resource at `http://api.example/foo/template` with `GET`
2. Edit properties, and
3. Submit the result again at a new endpoint to create the resource with `PUT` and `POST`.